# Apply excel macro to a cell within the same row if a value within another column

Tags: excel, macros

I'm trying to apply an excel macro to a cell if there is a certain value in that same row but in a different column. For example, if column A4 has "Yes", then the macro runs on A5.

Currently, I am listing out each of the cells where I need to apply the macro, but I don't want to have to change the macro every single time I need another cell to be added.

The code I have currently right now is as below.

Thank you!

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rngDV As Range
Dim oldVal As String
Dim newVal As String
Dim lUsed As Long
Dim iselect As Range
If Target.Count > 1 Then GoTo exitHandler

On Error Resume Next
Set rngDV = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)
On Error GoTo exitHandler

If rngDV Is Nothing Then GoTo exitHandler

If Intersect(Target, rngDV) Is Nothing Then
   'do nothing
Else
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  newVal = Target.Value
  Application.Undo
  oldVal = Target.Value
  Target.Value = newVal
  Set iselect = Application.Intersect(Target, Range("F28,F30,F77,F125,F176:F183,F185,F194,F196,F198:F205,F226,F364,F397,F400,F403,F451,F456,F545,F570,F572,F600,F605,F632,F638,F641,F646,F648,F673,F704,F706,F708,F712,F714,F716,F736,F765,F768,F798,F821,F823,F855,F884,F908,F947,F983:F984,F1009,F1015,F1026,F1033"))
  If Intersect(Target, iselect).Address = Target.Address Then
    If oldVal = "" Then
      'do nothing
      Else
      If newVal = "" Then
      'do nothing
      Else
        lUsed = InStr(1, oldVal, newVal)
        If lUsed > 0 Then
            If Right(oldVal, Len(newVal)) = newVal Then
                Target.Value = Left(oldVal, Len(oldVal) - Len(newVal) - 2)
            Else
                Target.Value = Replace(oldVal, newVal, "")
            End If
        Else
            Target.Value = oldVal _
              & "," & Chr(10) & newVal
        End If

      End If
    End If
  End If
End If

exitHandler:
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: You could make the range you want the macro to be applied to into a named range. Then you would just reference the named range in your script. If you want to add more cells to your macro just add the cells to your named range. Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: Also I am not big fans of this logic `If Intersect(Target, iselect).Address = Target.Address Then` as it would break for example for multi line copies (someone copies "Yes" to numerous cells at the same time). I prefer `If Not Intersect(Target, iselect) Is Nothing Then`. Or I would check to make sure the change event is firing on only 1 cell being changed.